# Image Download (Skip Bad Url)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Can anybody help me to fix this code I am having this error while downloading image in google sheet.

Exception: Error retrieving image from URL or bad URL:

[image]

```
function getImages() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const dataRange = sheet.getRange('I2:I' + sheet.getLastRow());
  const urls = dataRange.getValues().flat();


  const imageBuilders = urls.filter(url => url).map(url => SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url));
  const images = imageBuilders.map(imageBuilder => imageBuilder.build());


  images.forEach(function(image, i) {
    const cell = sheet.getRange(i + 2, 9);
    cell.setValue(image);
    sheet.setRowHeight(cell.getRow(), 250).setColumnWidth(cell.getColumn(), 100);
  });
}
```

I want to skip bad URL's. Right now code stop working if there is a bad URL available.

This is working for me it download and resize the image and column according to your need.

```
  const CONFIG = {
  imageWidth: 200,
  imageHeight: 150,
};

function getImages() {
  let sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.
  let sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (let i = 0; i < lastRow - 1; i++) {
    let url = sheet.getRange(2 + i, 9).getValue();
    let image = SpreadsheetApp.newCellImage().setSourceUrl(url).build();
    try {
      sheet.getRange(2 + i, 9).setValue(image);
      sheet.setRowHeight(2 + i, CONFIG.imageHeight);
      sheet.setColumnWidth(9, CONFIG.imageWidth);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e.message)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your showing URL and your showing script and your Spreadsheet. Can I ask you about the detail of your current situation?

Comment: I posted a solution under original question and is derived form your old code. Thank you so much and if you can make image downloading process more efficient will be great.